# How get values out of MSSQL with Ajax - PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, pdo, chart.js

I have a chart, which should get the data out of a MSSQL using Ajax and PHP.
I found several helpful answers on here, but they only apply for MySQL databases.

I can successfully connect to my MSSQL via a PDO class (dblib type), but when I try to execute my getdata.php file, it gives me a blank page.

If you need more info/code, let me know.

Here's what I have so far.

**getdata.php:**

```
<?php    
include ("PDO.php");     

$conn = DatabasePDO::getInstance();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Article";
$st = $conn->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$list = array();
while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
    $list[] = $row;
}
$conn = null;
echo json_encode($list);
?>
```

Comment: you are echoing `$row`, shouldn't you vardump `$list` instead?

Comment: what happens when you use `print_r($list);`?

Comment: @RST , still a blank page.

Comment: Did you put the print_r instead or before the json_encode? It should at least state that it is an Array. Put an `echo` statement inside the while loop see if anything shows up.

Comment: Gave me a blank page as well.
I rewrote the PDO class insite this php page, just as a test. And it worked.
Guess there's something wrong in my pdo class or my reference.
Thanks for your help !